# Weird gcc warning and sanitizer crash

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

I've encountered some weird gcc warning in my project. Let's look at this simple example in 3 files:

#### struct.h

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    long b;
    char *c;
} myStruct;
```

#### func.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "struct.h"

myStruct* func() {
    myStruct* new = (myStruct*) malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
    new->a = 42;
    new->b = 84;
    new->c = "lol_ok\n";
    return new;
}

void prn(myStruct* x) {
    printf("%d\n", x->a);
}
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "struct.h"

int main() {
    myStruct* ms = func();
    prn(ms);
    return 0;
}
```

So I get the following warning:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:8:24: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
         myStruct* ms = func();
```

Moreover when I build it with `-Wall -Wextra` I get more:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:8:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘func’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         myStruct* ms = func();
         ^
main.c:8:24: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
         myStruct* ms = func();
                        ^
main.c:9:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘prn’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  prn(ms);
```

What does it all mean? It also crashes if built with `-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address` and that's weird. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lack of prototype.

Include the prototype for `func()` in `struct.h`.

```
myStruct* func(void);
```

When there's no prototype visible for `func()`, compiler assumes (pre-C99) that it returns an `int`. But `func()` actually returns an `myStruct*`.

Note that this implicit int rule has been *removed* from C99. So technically, your code is ill-formed in C99 and C11.

Increasing your warning level would help. gcc provides [an option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) to catch this:

```
-Wimplicit-function-declaration
```

Answer (score 4):

```
main.c:8:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘func’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

That means that main.c doesn't know what the function `func` looks like.  That's because it's defined in func.c, but main.c can't see what's in func.c.

What you need to do is put a declaration for `func()` in struct.h, like so:

```
myStruct* func( void );
```

Once you have that there, then main.c knows what the function `func` is.

....

Also, the reason you get "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast" is because without seeing a declaration of the function, the compiler assumes it returns `int`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits No. Linker error will happen only if the function definition is not found (*undefined reference to blah*). But here, the definition does exist and available. Otherwise, gcc will fail rather than issuing a warning and defaulting int.